# Trying to get background-image filesize in greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, css, greasemonkey, background-image

I would like to get the filesize of a submit button's background-image with javascript/greasemonkey.

<s>P.s. I don't want to reload the page or make new calls to the image. Since the image is different each load.</s>

The image is not different each time, only the name and url are :D

Sorry about that.. :/

Thanks, all, I solved the rest of my problem myself :)

Comment: Can you post some code with what you've attempted?

Comment: The question is not clear.  Do you really want the filesize size of the button control, or do you actually want the size of a file about to be uploaded?   The former can be had using browser tools (what browser are you using?).  The latter can be had by looking at your local file system.  If neither, then there's no point in using GM unless you're trying to sneak this script onto someone else's machine?

Comment: I want the filesize of the button's background image. (Without reloading the page.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function filesize (url) {
        // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
        // +   original by: Enrique Gonzalez
        // +      input by: Jani Hartikainen
        // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
        // +   improved by: T. Wild
        // %        note 1: This function uses XmlHttpRequest and cannot retrieve resource from different domain.
        // %        note 1: Synchronous so may lock up browser, mainly here for study purposes.
        // *     example 1: filesize('http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/pj_test_supportfile_1.htm');
        // *     returns 1: '3'

        var req = this.window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (!req) {throw new Error('XMLHttpRequest not supported');}

        req.open('HEAD', url, false);
        req.send(null);

        if (!req.getResponseHeader) {
            try {
                throw new Error('No getResponseHeader!');
            } catch (e){
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!req.getResponseHeader('Content-Length')) {
            try {
                throw new Error('No Content-Length!');
            } catch (e2){
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return req.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');
        }
    }
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    input[type="submit"] {
        background-image: url("images/button_submit.gif");
    }
</style>

<body>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(filesize($('input[type="submit"]').css("background-image").match(/url\(\"(.*)\"\)/)[1]));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> "I don't want to reload the page or make new calls to the image. Since the image is different each load."

There is no way to get this information in JavaScript or Greasemonkey without a second call to the server.   You would need to write your own add-on/extension to get that programmatically on the first call.

However, you can see background-image, filesize, right now.  Just right-click on the page and select *View Page Info* (Firefox) and then click the Media tab.

Also, you can install the [Web Developer add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/).  It can show image information, including BG image, filesize.

Comment: This helped me find the solution too, too bad that's not possible though.